# OpenXmlPowerTools.HtmlConverter.ConvertToHtml() converting bullets to ?(question mark)

Tags: c#, asp.net, openxml

In my website, client can import word file.I am converting this word file to html.

> The issue I am facing is the returned html is returning ? for the
>   unordered bullets.

As a test,I checked recreating the .docx file from the memory stream, Here no issues.

```
        try
        {

            var fi = new FileInfo(filePath + "/" + fileName);
            string outputDirectory = filePath.Replace("ImportFiles", "XmlFiles");
            byte[] byteArray = File.ReadAllBytes(fi.FullName);
            using (MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
            {
                memoryStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);
                using (WordprocessingDocument wDoc = WordprocessingDocument.Open(memoryStream, true))
                {
                    var destFileName = new FileInfo(fi.Name.Replace(".docx", ".xml"));
                    if (outputDirectory != null && outputDirectory != string.Empty)
                    {
                        DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo(outputDirectory);
                        if (!di.Exists)
                        {
                            throw new OpenXmlPowerTools.OpenXmlPowerToolsException("Output directory does not exist");
                        }
                        destFileName = new FileInfo(Path.Combine(di.FullName, destFileName.Name));
                    }
                    var imageDirectoryName = destFileName.FullName.Substring(0, destFileName.FullName.Length - 5) + "_files";
                    int imageCounter = 0;
                    string imageFileName = "", resourceFileName ="";
                    var pageTitle = (string)wDoc.CoreFilePropertiesPart.GetXDocument().Descendants(DC.title).FirstOrDefault();
                    if (pageTitle == null)
                        pageTitle = fi.FullName;
                    imageDirectoryName = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "Temp";
                    HtmlConverterSettings settings = new HtmlConverterSettings()
                    {
                        PageTitle = pageTitle,
                        FabricateCssClasses = true,
                        CssClassPrefix = "pt-",
                        RestrictToSupportedLanguages = false,
                        RestrictToSupportedNumberingFormats = false,
                     }
                    XElement html = OpenXmlPowerTools.HtmlConverter.ConvertToHtml(wDoc, settings);



                    var htmlString = html.ToString(SaveOptions.DisableFormatting);
                    File.WriteAllText(destFileName.FullName, htmlString, Encoding.UTF8);
                    string bodyContent = GetBodyContent(htmlString, destFileName.FullName);
                    // File.WriteAllText(destFileName.FullName, bodyContent, Encoding.UTF8);
                    ReadXmlAndSaveData(documentKey,parentID, userId, clientId, destFileName.FullName, fileName, imageDirectoryName);
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw
        }
        return "";
    }
```

Any help highly appreciated.

Comment: Maybe you want to make your code cleaner and separate into individual methods. This process is called refactoring. Makes it much easier to read and understand. Ideally, make it a [mcve]

Comment: @ThomasWeller, completly agree but this is written by someone else. Its been assigned to me fix as urgent fix

Comment: You quick fix it now, someone else quick fix it next and finally it'll just be a mess. Good luck.

Comment: @ThomasWeller okay :)